# Usando .get() em ua janela com tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

quando tento usar o código:

```
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()

texto = tk.Text(window).pack()
tk.mainloop()
print(texto.get())
```

para me retornar o valor do que escrevi na variavel texto o programa me retorna este erro:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'

usando console do Python consegui rodar ele sem problema, existe alguma maneira de fazer ele executar ele sem o uso do console?

Comment: .pack() retorna None, vc provavelmente não esta usando as exatas linhas  no terminal e no script

Answer (score 1):

Bom, pelo que eu entendi, você quer imprimir a resposta escrita na janela do Tkinter. Eu não consegui compreender se você quer imprimir no terminal ou a própria janela. Farei uma demonstração para cada uma das possibilidades, certo? Vamos lá.

### Impressão da resposta no terminal

```
from tkinter import * 
root = Tk()

#Criando o frame e estabelecendo configurações
arq = Frame(bg = "lightgrey")
arq["padx"] = 80
arq["pady"] = 5
arq.pack(fill='both', expand=True)

#Criando espaço para input no frame
inp = Entry(arq)
inp["width"] = 71
inp.configure(font = "Quicksand 12", bg = "white")
inp.pack(side=LEFT)

#Função para exibir o valor dado no terminal
def exibir():
   print(inp.get())

#Criando botão para imprimir
bot_visualizar = Button(root, text = "Imprimir", command = exibir)
bot_visualizar.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

### Impressão da resposta na janela

```
from tkinter import * 
root = Tk()

#Criando o frame e estabelecendo configurações
arq = Frame(bg = "lightgrey")
arq["padx"] = 80
arq["pady"] = 5
arq.pack(fill='both', expand=True)

#Criando espaço para input no frame
inp = Entry(arq)
inp["width"] = 71
inp.configure(font = "Quicksand 12", bg = "white")
inp.pack(side=LEFT)

#Função para exibir o valor dado no terminal
def exibir():
   l = Label (arq, text= inp.get())
   l["padx"] = 20
   l["pady"] = 5
   l.configure(font = "Quicksand 12 bold", bg = "lightgrey")
   l.pack (side="left",fill="y")

#Criando botão para imprimir
bot_visualizar = Button(root, text = "Imprimir", command = exibir)
bot_visualizar.pack()

root.mainloop()
```